# Rendering PDF without going back to server (wicked_pdf)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I am using wicked_pdf to render PDF.  The app renders a table in HTML.  This table is dynamic, in the sense that, the data in it changes every 30 seconds.  When the user clicks on the "Download as PDF" link, the request goes back to the server and the HTML (slightly modified for PDF) is rendered.

But the issue is that since the request is back to the server, the data would have changed.  This results in the PDF table showing values differing from the HTML table.  The client doesn't want this.

Basically, they want a snapshot of the static table in PDF form, not the dynamic table.  How can I do this using wicked_pdf?

Thanks,
Sridhar

Comment: Just pass the contents of your table back to the server to create a PDF as a parameter.

Comment: Do you mean sending the table's HTML as a string parameter?  I was considering that.

Comment: so why this way doesnt meet your requirements?

Comment: I was concerned about the parameter becoming too long.

Comment: You can config it in your webserver. Mostly all POST-parameters are less than 2Mb. I think 2Mb should be enough for your task.

Answer (score 1):

Common Rails way here is to use timestamps.

You should pass your actual time to your controller, so it will fetch only supposed items, like.

```
# views
= link_to "pdf", orders_path(updated_at: DateTime.now, format: :pdf)
# controller
orders = Order.where(updated_at >= params[:updated_at])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no easy way of getting this information in the existing db structure.  [I am forced to use a legacy db that the client uses.]

I was considering creating temporary db views and use the session-id as a parameter.  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I understand. So you can use temporary db, but you'll need to create some cleanup logic to remove old data etc. Or you can really send raw html as a string to some pdf generation controller. Or. If your buiseness logic allow you to fetch specific items. you can pass only ids and generate pdf depending on ids